# Polya's enumeration theorem problem.

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, symmetric-groups, symmetry

Consider a necklace contains $2m$ elements. We want to determine some combinatorical number (for example number of ways to color them). We may use P.E.T. But firstly it's need to determine group of representation of necklace. This group $G$ contains $2m$ rotations and the same amount of symmetries.

But there is a problem. If we consider regular polygon with $2m$ vertices and consider the same problem - then we need to consider only rotations. What's the defference between them?

Comment: This question is too open ended to answer. But generally, if two sets have an identical group action on them, that doesn't imply that the sets are identical. In this case, however, I don't suspect this being an issue.

Comment: @DonThousand I just interested in why we should consider only rotations in one case, and symmetries also in other.

Comment: What do you mean only rotations? Polygons have symmetries too!

Comment: @DonThousand I unerstand that. But if we need to consider number of colors with $n$ colors and we use P.E.T. then we consider symmetries in one case, and dont in other.

Comment: @DonThousand maybe I bad in explanation. Let me repeat again : to find number of ways to color regular polygon, or necklace - we need to determine symmetry group of objects. It's easy to see that necklaces and regular polygons has the same symmetry group. But that's not true that $F(n,m)$ = $G(n,m)$, where $F,G$ - number of ways to color them into $n$ colors. The main difference that we consider only rotations in regular polygons and consider rotations and symmetries in other case. What's the difference ?

Comment: Are we talking about the distinction between "necklace" and "bracelet", as least as defined in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) intro section?

Comment: @antkam I guess so.